# Foundation 6.4.1 - how to fix the dropdown menu width?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

How can I fix the width of the dropdown menu items?

```css
.row,
.grid-container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.menu>li>a {
  line-height: 40px;
}

.menu>li>a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.menu ul li a {
  line-height: normal;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.menu ul {
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/css/foundation.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <ul class="menu align-center dropdown" data-dropdown-menu>
    <li>
      <a href="#">One</a>
      <ul class="menu vertical">
        <li><a href="#">One One One One One very long title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

As you can see I have fixed the dropdown menu items to **200px** but the item with the long text is running **outside** the box. How can I fix the width so that the text is **always inside** the box? What is the correct way doing it? If the text is very long, then it should break the text into multiple lines.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this class "ul.vertical li a"

and add title to the a tag

```css
.row,
.grid-container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.menu>li>a {
  line-height: 40px;
}

.menu>li>a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

.menu ul li a {
  line-height: normal;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
ul.vertical li a {
display: inline-block;
max-width: 100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden!important;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.menu ul {
  max-width: 100px;
}
.dropdown.menu>li.opens-right>.is-dropdown-submenu{
min-width: 100px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/css/foundation.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.1/js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <ul class="menu align-center dropdown" data-dropdown-menu>
    <li>
      <a href="#">One</a>
      <ul class="menu vertical">
        <li><a href="#" title="One One One One One very long title<">One One One One One very long title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But it is still not what I am after. If I change the dropdown width lower than 200px, eg. 100px, it seems that we cannot over-write the foundation's default.

Comment: you give ul.vertical li a {max-width: 100%;} and it would take the width of the parent tag

Comment: yes i know that. I mean to change the width of the parent to lower than 200px.

Comment: How about now !? to do that i added the class

.dropdown.menu>li.opens-right>.is-dropdown-submenu{
min-width: 100px !important;
}

Comment: thank you for updating it. it change the width of the parent now. it is great. but is it possible to break the long text **naturally** into multiple lines instead of current solution which is using `ellipsis`?

Comment: yes, you can use white-space: pre-line; in ul.vertical li a class instead of white-space: nowrap; and please marke this question as resolved 
if you found what you was locking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150076/discussion-between-m0ns1f-and-teelou).